# cannot find -lmysqlclient collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: linker, g++, eclipse-cdt

Invoking: Cygwin C++ Linker
g++ -nostartfiles -L"E:\cygwin\lib\mysql\lib" -lmysqlclient -lz -shared -o"final.so"  ./src/one.o ./src/two.o ./src/three.o ./src/four.o ./src/five.o
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.3.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: this is not google, and yours is not a question but an error message

Comment: error msg is for reference ... I dont know whats the problem here..why this error is coming

Answer (score 1):

The error message states that the mysqlclient library cannot be found. Since you're using Cygwin the issue might be that you're using a Windows-style path **-L"E:\cygwin\lib\mysql\lib"**. I believe the GNU C++ Linker expects a Unix-style path, such as **-L"/lib/mysql/lib"**.

Without more specific information it's hard to say though.

Comment: @ERIK Some more details >
libmysqlclient.so is present under E:\cygwin\lib\mysql\lib n somehow that is not getting linked properly.
I dont think its path prb coz compilation phase excuted properly with the same path.
can u plz tell how to do it

Comment: Under Project->properties->C++ Build->settings->Cygwin c++ Linker->Libraries

Added following 

Libraries (-l) 
mysqlclient.so

Library search path (-L)
E:\cygwin\lib\mysql\lib

Comment: I don't think g++ tries to use the -L paths during compile phase, so you won't notice the problem there.

Comment: Even after path changes ----> Building target: final.so Invoking: Cygwin C++ Linker g++ -o"final.so" ./src/one.o ./src/two.o ./src/three.o ./src/four.o ./src/five.o -nostartfiles -L/cygdrive/e/cygwin/usr/local/lib -lmysqlclient -lz -shared /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.3.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make: * [final.so] Error 1